# show or hide navigation menu items based on user role in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a requirement to show or hide few menus/tabs in my navigation menu.
I'm using register_nav_menu() routine in wordpress (CMS) to add navigation menu

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/) might be the easiest way.

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion, yes I agree with you that using this plugin , it would make by job easy.I'm just trying to do the same with wordpress provided functions/primitives

Comment: If the plugin does what you want it to do, you can always just look at its code and borrow ideas for your own

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the roles of a user by:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
print_r($user->roles);
```

This way you can validate all the roles the current user has and display or not your menus.

Comment: This would help decide whether or not to display the entire menu, but it seems like it would be harder to use this to hide only certain menu items...